# How to install gtk development dependencies on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I have the code from [GTK tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.24/c39.html) in `base.c`.

I am working on **Ubuntu** and when I compile using

```
$ gcc base.c -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I get the following *error*

```
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
base.c:1:20: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Being new to *linux*, can someone help me in setting up the environment so that I can *compile/run* the program successfully?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Generally speaking to build things based on `libfoo`, you need `libfoo-dev`.

In addition, to install anything that is needed to build a package, say `gedit`, you can run:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gedit
```

Searching http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or Synaptic can help.